# Use curl to send binary file through POST with content-type multipart/form-data;

Tags: linux, curl, binary, data

A post request is made to:

```
http://www.example.com/example/
```

and the post data is as follows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryB8NNdk2kNdndnnn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture[uploaded_data]"; filename="picture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

binarydatagoeshere
------WebKitFormBoundaryB8NNdk2kNdndnnn--
```

So my question is, how can i use curl to do this exact same thing with the binary data of picture.jpg? I know of --data-binary @myfile.bin, but this is completely different and in this case the string after Boundary e.g `B8NNdk2kNdndnnn` in this case needs to be valid for the request to go through.
So how do i do all this using curl?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `--form` option should do what you need:

```
curl --form "picture[uploaded_data]=@picture.jpg;type=image/jpeg" http://www.example.com/example/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample script in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) to POST multipart. You need to adapt it a bit :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    autocheck => 1,
    agent_alias => 'Mozilla',
    cookie_jar => {},
    ssl_opts => {verify_hostname => 0},
    quiet => 0,
);
$m->get("http://domain.tld");                                                   

$m->post('https://domain.tld/send',
    Content_Type => "form-data",
    Content => [
        'picture[uploaded_data]' => 'foobar',
        file => [ '/path/to/image', 'image_name', 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg' ]
    ]
);

print $m->content;
```

Check http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm